# Split list into list of lists by regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a character list into a list of lists, where the split point is defined by successful Regex match.

For instance, say I have an input list:

```
["file1","A","B","C","file2","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
```

I want to produce:

```
[["file1","A","B","C"],["file2","D","E","F","G","H","I"]]
```

Where the split points, being `file1` and `file2` were identified by a successful match to

```
re.search("file[0-9]+",<TEST STRING>)
```

It is NOT known in advance, the number of items between each split point, nor is it known how many 'fileXXX' terms are in the original vector.

In reality, my Regex matches are a lot more complicated than this, that is not the concern, what I need help with, if someone would be so kind, is the Pythonic way to execute the split logic?

Comment: What are the rules? Why you want to group "A", "B" and "C" with "file1"? I don't think that regex is what you need here.

Comment: Because I have a large concatenated log file, originating from 'n' smaller sequential log files, and I want to reverse the concatination at a known header line, which I can match by regex.

Comment: Now I understand you.. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work quite nicely:

```
import re

input_list = ["file1","A","B","C","file2","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
output_list = []

for item in input_list:
    if re.match("file[0-9]+", item):
        output_list.append([item])
    else:
        output_list[-1].append(item)

print output_list
```

Gives the following result:

```
[['file1', 'A', 'B', 'C'], ['file2', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']]
```

Note, this assumes the first item is a match.

**Update**

A second approach could be:

```
input_list = ["1", "2", "file1","A","B","C","file2","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
output_list = []

for item in input_list:
    if re.match("file[0-9]+", item) or len(output_list) == 0:
        output_list.append([item])
    else:
        output_list[-1].append(item)

print output_list
```

This would also cope with the non initial match case:

```
[['1', '2'], ['file1', 'A', 'B', 'C'], ['file2', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']]
```

Comment: I like this the best: particularly if instead of the 'else' condition, you used elif len(output_list) > 0:, which handles the case when first item is not a match

Answer (score 3):

Assumes the first element will be a proper header. If not, you will need to do some defensive clauses.

```
import re
result = []
pattern = re.compile(r'^file.*')
for el in input_list:
    if pattern.match(el):
        row = []
        result.append(row)
    row.append(el)
```

Comment: @AnandSKumar: And yet, it [works](http://preview.tinyurl.com/obs5oqb). (Hint: I am not adding the contents of a filled `row`. I am adding a *reference* to an empty row, to be filled in later.)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the indexes of `file\d`:

```
indeces = list(i for i,val in enumerate(my_list) if match('file\d', val))
```

And then simply group by these indexes:

```
output = [my_list[indeces[0]:indeces[1]], my_list[indeces[1]:]]
```

---

```
>>> from re import match
>>> my_list = ["file1","A","B","C","file2","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
>>> indeces = list(i for i,val in enumerate(my_list) if match('file\d', val))
>>> [my_list[indeces[0]:indeces[1]], my_list[indeces[1]:]]
[['file1', 'A', 'B', 'C'], ['file2', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']]
```

Comment: Thx, I just updated my question, should have said also that the number of 'fileXXX' terms in the original vector are not known, could be 1, could be 100 ....

Comment: @NicholasHamilton then the code should be generalized, I'll think about a solution as soon as I'll get home later.